# making mouse click action obvious in a screen-cast video-capture

Tags: video-capture, screen-casting

One of the challenges, in creating a tutorial video via screen video capture, is that it becomes a challenge to make obvious which mouse action was used to produce a certain action on the screen.

The creator of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNhN3X3MvD4) has a little mouse icon in the bottom left of the screen (see image below) that makes clear whether he's using the left, the middle, or the right mouse click button action.

[image: screen video capture, with mouse icon in bottom left that indicates which mouse action is being performed (left, middle, or right mouse click)]

How does one add such a mouse icon (or alternatively, which software allows this) to a screen video capture? (I've asked the original creator on multiple fora, but haven't heard back for months).

Comment: Is this a Blender question? That feature is a Blender specific plugin.

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite Nope. Wasn't a Blender question. But your answer answered it for me. I guess this is a Blender feature. If you answer below, I'll mark it correct. Bonus if you also put a link to the actual plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a Blender specific plugin that you can activate in the scripts menu.

https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Screencast_Key_Status_Tool